# How to open and close wiQuery Dialogs?

Tags: java, wicket, wiquery

I'm trying out [wiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) to see if it suits my needs, but I've run into problems with very basic stuff. Consider the following, where I try to control when a Dialog opens and closes, using its `open()` and `close()` methods:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" wicket:id="open" value="Open dialog"/>    
<div wicket:id="dialog">    
    <input type="submit" wicket:id="close" value="Close"/>    
</div>
```

Java:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("dialog");

add(new Link("open") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        dialog.open();
    }
});

dialog.add(new Link("close") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        dialog.close();
    }   
});

add(dialog);
```

Thing is, the above doesn't work.

The only way I've got the dialog to actually open & close from my code is by calling **setAutoOpen()** with either true or false, but it seems strange is this is the only way. (That method's Javadoc says "Sets if this window opens autmatically after the page is loaded." so it clearly *should* be reserved for a different purpose.)

**What's the right way of opening and closing wiQuery Dialogs dynamically in your code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the last 2 weeks and I have a similar problem. Try using an AjaxLink this way:

```
AjaxLink openingLink = new AjaxLink("open")
{

  @Override
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
  {
    // Do something with model
    target.addComponent(content);
    dialog.open(target);
  }

};
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Hmm, it's actually pretty obvious that you need an AjaxLink for something like this. :) Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks, I've been a long-term reader/observer but a bit shy on commenting :)
I feel like an eternal apprentice